# Session usage in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2008, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

In my wcf project, I want to store some user information(userid or something) as we use asp.net session.After logging in, the userid will store in session
and we can retrieve it for other service.I found we can use httpcontext.current.session in wcf but that one is only support for wcf hosted in IIS.
My wcf service will be hosted in window service.Is there any way to do? Is there any variable or function in wcf to get that features?
Please guide me the right way.Thanks for your help.

```
//For example 

//LogOnWCFService
 public Boolean LogOn(string userID, string PWD)
 {
     currentUserID = userID;
     HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserID",userID);
     return true;
 }

//ProcessWCFService
public void Process()
{
    string userid = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    if(userid == 1)
    {
       //Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of `sessions` with WCF, espescially if you want to use the session data over different Service calls. 
A better approach would be to implement your own session management. The `LogOnService` could create an unique `sesion ID` after a successfull logon and return it to the client. The `session ID` could be persisted together with additional informations (UserID etc.). All other services then include this `session ID` in every method call to identitfy itself.

```
 nSess = logscv.LogOn(UserID)....procsvc.Process(nSess)
```